# Is it possible to write cross database join queries?

Tags: java, mysql, database, oracle, postgresql

Multiple Databases on Multiple Servers from Different Vendors the databases are on different servers and some of the servers run different database software. For example, the customers database may be hosted on machine X on Oracle, and the orders database may be hosted on machine Y with Microsoft SQL. Is it possible to write join queries and which framework best suits for the case (Spring, ASP.NET 
 or any other)?

Answer (score 0):

In PostgreSQL you can map and join tables:

From MySQL, HDFS and MongoDB using EnterpriseDB's foreign data wrappers - https://github.com/EnterpriseDB/

From SQL server - https://github.com/tds-fdw/tds_fdw

From Oracle - https://github.com/laurenz/oracle_fdw

Comment: What about other database systems such as Oracle, MSSQL?

Answer (score -1):

Yes,it is possible to write cross database join queries.In oracle you can create DB link for another database and access the schemas in that DB using DBlinkk@schema_name.

Full documentation is present here:

```
[https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_5005.htm][1]
```